# Arabic TTS using iOS built in Speech Synthesizer

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

A part of my app requires using TTS for speaking Arabic words with Tahreek. Arabic characters may have some signs on them to change the way these are pronounced.

The following works well for the most part:

```
let pickedWord = "تُفَّاح"
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:pickedWord!)
utterance.rate = rate
utterance.volume = volume
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: voiceLanguageCode)
speechSynthesizer.speakUtterance(utterance)
```

However the "فَّ" is supposed to be pronounced (twice but linked), something like "فف" but this is not working. I've seen another app where this is pronounced correctly but there are no indicators if they have been using pre-recorded sounds or the built-in functionality. Has anyone experienced this issue before and if you know of anyway to resolve and get it to pronounce correctly. I have already tried slowing down the speech rate but that doesn't work.

One more thing, I am wondering if anyone found a way to get the speech synthesize to pronounce the Arabic "ف" as a "V" I did find that the letter 'ڤْ' works when by itself but for some reason it doesn't when in the middle of a word. Words like Avocado sound weird when pronounced with the Arabic "ف" like "F", becoming Afocado!

Also found that the same applies to the Arabic PEH (پ) as well. Ended up filing a bug report with Apple, will update if anything happens. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you using for voiceLanguageCode?  MSA?

Comment: Nevermind... There's only one for Arabic.

Comment: Yes, only one ar-sa! Still stuck with that and it seems like a TTS/synthesizer system limitation.

Comment: I am afraid you are correct.  I tried looking up ways to modify it, but I have not been able to find anything.  Best of luck!  Salaam alekum